# Why does *h* have two different names in Welsh?

Tags: alphabets, welsh

Why does *h* have two different names in Welsh, namely *âets* and *hâ* (variants: *ha*, *he*, *hi*, *hy*)? And what other examples are there of letters known in a language under two or more names *for the same reasons*? (The reasons for *âets* and *hâ* may not be the same as those for either *zed* and *zee* or *aitch* and *haitch* in English).

Comment: I would think the most popular name for it would by _hy_. I never write the names of the letters, but that's certainly how I would pronounce it when saying the alphabet. I have never heard anyone say _hâ_.

Comment: My guess would be borrowing.

Answer (score 2):

i don't know anyone who says âets or hâ, it is more or less always pronounced hy when reciting the alphabet and such. i'm not sure where you got the hâ idea from, but âets is most likely borrowed from english